# Run a self-defined program repeatedly until two components of a matrix is 0?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I'm not familiar with matlab at all, and I have an in-class project to complete it with.

I have a self-defined .m function named L1 (a linear program). I want to repeat L1 and increase one of the variables, tau by a factor of 2 until two components of w (a 31x1 matrix) are zero, while also zeroing out components of w that are below threshold [image: equation]

I know this is very wrong, but I'm not really much of a programmer. So I'm thinking of maybe doing a while loop? Something long the lines of:

```
%runs program once to get values of w
tau = 0.1
fracTest = 0.1 %these are just variables
reord = 0 %more variables
[train,~,~,~] = wdbcData(input_file, dataDim, fracTest, reord); %another self-defined function
[w, gamm, obj, misclass] = separateL1(train, 1:dataDim, tau, quiet);

while w > 0
    tau = tau*2
    [train,~,~,~] = wdbcData(input_file, dataDim, fracTest, reord);
    [w, gamm, obj, misclass] = separateL1(train, 1:dataDim, tau, quiet);

    %checks threshold value
    if w < 10^-6 * norm(w, Inf) 
     w = 0
    end

end
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually did a quite good job, just a little bit optimisation here and fixed some minor errors.

```
fracTest = 0.1 %these are just variables
reord = 0 %more variables
tau = 0.1

w = [1 1]; %set w to some non-zero value initially
while isequal(w,[0 0])
    tau = tau*2
    [train,~,~,~] = wdbcData(input_file, dataDim, fracTest, reord);
    [w, gamm, obj, misclass] = separateL1(train, 1:dataDim, tau, quiet);

    %checks threshold value
    th = 10^-6*norm(w, Inf)
    if w(1) < th 
     w(1) = 0
    end
    if w(2) < th 
     w(2) = 0
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry, a quick follow up question. What would I do if `w` is a 31x1 matrix and I'd like to see if any of those 31 values are zero? I'm guessing I'd define a similar matrix full of `1`s and use the argument `while isequal(length(find(w==0))> 2, one_matrix)`?

Comment: @Nikitau `isequal(w,zeros(size(w)))` will work. `zeros(size(w))` creates a matrix/array of zeros with size identical to w.

Comment: Sorry I keep coming back with problems. Apparently I don't have a 'true' 0 (i.e: my routine returns somethig like 0.0000001 which comes back at 0.0000). So now I want to set something like: `while ~isequal(length(find(w<0.0001))> 2, true([31,1]))`, but I'm thinking this only breaks out of the while loop when all of `w < 0.000`? How do I change this so that as long as any two components of w is 0 I break out of the loop?

Comment: @Nikitau no worries, I'm here till your problem is solved. In this case, you can have this `while sum(w<0.0001)<2`. Here `w<0.0001` will return an array of size `w`, containing only 1 and 0. If `w(i)<0.00001`, the returned array at `i` is 1 otherwise 0. So calculating the sum of it will tell you how many elements in w are ~0.